# making a python bitarray from an integer - strange results!

Tags: python, bit-fields, bitarray

I'm just starting to use the bitarray package in python, and trying to make a bitarray from an integer gives me really confusing results:

```
>>> import bitarray
>>> bitarray.bitarray(5)
bitarray('01000')
>>> bitarray.bitarray(5)
bitarray('00010')
>>> bitarray.bitarray(5)
bitarray('00100')
>>> bitarray.bitarray(5)
bitarray('00110')
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening??

Also: what would be a better way of making a bitarray from an int? This works, but string conversion seems like a strange way to do it...

```
>>> bitarray.bitarray(bin(5)[2:])
bitarray('101')
```

**Edit:** I ended up switching to [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/), which does have an easy method of getting bitstrings from ints:

```
>>> bitstring.BitArray(uint=5,length=6)
BitArray('0b000101')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bitarray.bitarray(n)` creates an *uninitialized* array of length `n`.

As far as creating from an integer, `bitarray` doesn't appear to be particularly geared towards that, so you'll either have to use `pack/unpack` or loop over the individual bits to set them.

Comment: ...Duh!  I have no idea why I didn't think of that.  That is obviously what it's doing.  Thanks!

Comment: The reason a fromint() function does not exist is that "integer" is somewhat poorly defined in Python.  long() and int() are both integer types, so instead of supporting either it seems to prefer the neutral interface of .frombytes(), which it seems fairly easy to wrangle other base types into.

Answer (score 5):

```py
>>> from bitarray.util import int2ba
>>> int2ba(5)
bitarray('101')
```

From the [project page](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) under "Functions defined in bitarray.util module:".